# Where can I find applications of Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis to physics?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, physics, book-recommendation

Sheldon Axler (Professor Emeritus at San Francisco State University) has a textbook called *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis* which (as far as I know) covers the basics of measure theory and functional analysis, along with a bit of Fourier analysis and probability theory.

There is an [Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RHZIUS4EFSG4W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0825PBNMP) of Professor Axler's book that says

> ... These results are of course very important in that they all have applications in mathematical physics. ...

I would like to know where to look in order to find these applications.

My (mostly uneducated) guess is that I should be looking more towards quantum mechanics and/or maybe particle theory (as opposed to, say, classical mechanics or general relativity). So, perhaps I should be looking at texts like *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* by Hall, and *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai and Napolitano.

Does anyone have any guidance to offer? Thanks.

Comment: The applications of measure theory are something those taking an intro physics 1/2 would see. Integrating over charge or mass like $W = \int V\:dq$ and $I = \int r^2 \: dm$ cannot be interpreted as Riemann integrals in any sense. These integrals are applications of the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Comment: Does the comment answer your question?

Comment: I'm frankly unsure. I don't know enough physics or measure theory to understand your examples, and some searching on Google didn't yield much that connected the Radon-Nikodym theorem to things like "charge" or "mass".

Comment: @NinadMunshi Is something like this (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4471-5122-7_11) or this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798654/radon-measure-as-a-representation-of-density) relevant to what you're saying?

Comment: This is a connection I made on my own. To date I have never, ever seen a book, paper, or set of notes connect these concepts to the radon nikodym theorem - however the connection is obvious if you are familiar with one or the other.